# jquery: double function under .hover or .click doesn't always work

Tags: jquery

I would like to make #click disappear and #hint appear when the user clicks on #click. I tried two formats, the first format works and I'm wondering why the second format doesn't work.

**First Format:**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0);
});
$('#click').click(function() {
    $('#hint').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

**Second Format**

```
$('#click').click(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0);
        },
        function() {
            $('#hint').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }
    );
```

**Reference format used for First format** (which works)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'double function' version for the `click` event. You first format simply attaches two click event handler functions.

Just call your methods in one function:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0);
    $('#hint').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do this, you don't need multiple click event on the button.

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0);
    $('#hint').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`hover` has 2 functions, one when you enter, the other when you exit the element.
`click` has only one.